# How to use ldp in Windows with kerberos credentials to bind to OpenLDAP

Tags: windows-7, ldap, kerberos, sasl

I want to do an LDAP search from my Windows 7 workstation against our organization's OpenLDAP instance. This OpenLDAP instance requires GSSAPI (i.e., Kerberos) credentials to work.

On Linux I do this:

```
% kinit johndoe
% Password for johndoe@example.com: <password>
% ldapsearch -h ldap.example.com <my search>
```

This works fine.

On my Windows workstation I tried something similar:

```
PS C:\Users\johndoe> kinit johndoe
PS C:\Users\johndoe> Password for johndoe@example.com: <password>
PS C:\Users\johndoe> ldp ldap.example.co
```

The `ldp` utility causes a window to pop-up. There are several choices for binding including "Bind as currently logged on user" and "Advanced (SASL)" but nothing I try works. All I get are bind errors.

The OpenLDAP instance runs on Debian Linux and authenticates against a Kerberos domain running Heimdal Kerberos (also running on Debian Linux).

Comment: Do you use MIT kinit on Windows?

Comment: How do I know if the kinit on my machine is MIT?

Comment: I _am_ using MIT kinit.

Comment: You did not say what your Kerberos realm is. Is it an AD domain or a separate Kerberos realm on with the OpenLDAP server as back-end?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify how the OpenLDAP instance authenticates.

Answer (score 0):

LDP.EXE uses the ticket cache of your Windows session (LSASS).

See also: [Credentials Processes in Windows Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication)

If you're using MIT Kerberos for Windows then I suspect it's using its own ticket cache. But IIRC it can be configured to use MSLSA ccache.

See also: [ccache types](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/basic/ccache_def.html#ccache-types)